# SVG tspan rendering differences - bug in IE or Chrome or both?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, svg, internet-explorer-11

Question:

The below SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <rect id="rect2993" x="20" y="40" width="1000" height="300" style="fill:#aa0000" />
<!--
  <text x="20" y="40">Example SVG text 1</text>
-->

  <text id="txtErrorTitle" x="20" y="40" style="font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#aa0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Sans;"
   xml:space="preserve" >

        <tspan id="tspan2994" x="10" y="67" style="fill:#FF00FF">
          System.Web.HttpException
        </tspan>

        <tspan id="tspan29914" x="10" y="100" style="fill:#FF00FF">
            System.Web.HttpException
        </tspan>

    </text>

  <circle cx="20" cy="40" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.75" />
  <circle cx="1020" cy="340" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.75" />


  <circle cx="10" cy="67" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" fill-opacity="0.75" />

  <text x="1020" y="340" fill="red" transform="rotate(45 1020,340)">I am rotated SVG text</text>


  <foreignObject class="node" x="46" y="422" width="200" height="300">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>
        The quick brown fox jumps <font style="color: hotpink;">over</font> the lazy dog. <br />Pack my box with
        five dozen liquor jugs
      </div>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

renders in IE like I'd expect it:

[image: SVG Internet Explorer]

However, in Chrome and FireFox, it renders like this:

[image: Firefox / Chrome]

While I post this question, I just realized that the foreign object does not render in IE, which is no surprise since IE has always been buggy and lagging behind. But my actual question is not about the foreign object.

My actual question is: 
**Why is the position of the text "System.Web.HttpException" not at position (10,67) and (10,100) in Chrome/FireFox ?** 
Is that a bug in the rendering in Chrome/FireFox ? 
Or am I missing something SVG-wise, and it's IE who is buggy again ?

What I find especially strange is that the second tspan is appx. 10 to the right of the previous tspan element.
It almost seems like the tspan coordinates are relative to the preceding element, but then it's strange that there's no Y-offset of 67.547935...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xml:space](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#WhiteSpace)="preserve" makes whitespace count and there's more whitespace before the second text. Looks like IE does not support xml:space="preserve"

Comment: That's it. Thanks ! Removed it, works now. xml:space="preserve"came from inkscape. It's IE who is buggy AGAIN, as suspected. One needs to select "Plain SVG" when saving from InkScape, otherwise it uses InkScape SVG...